# Why secure lock disappear from my wordpress website after applying SSL certificate?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have applied SSL certificate on my wordpress website. When i load site secure lock shows for few seconds and then disappears. how can i debug what is issue?

Comment: This is probably better asked either on the [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site or the [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site. Please have a look around to see if someone has already asked about this topic on those sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your images and/or requests are sent via https not http.

So, instead of:
http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/logo.png
use this:
https://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/logo.png

Also, check if your .htaccess file has the rules to redirect to https, heres the code in case you need it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```